# Android Marketplace: Changing application's package

Tags: android, google-play

Any android developers had any success changing the package name of your application (in the manifest) of an application already being distributed in the Market?

During my upgrade progress, I decided to change the package name slightly, which means that android identifies it as a new application. So, I suppose saved preferences will be lost, but I'm really hoping there are no other "surprises" for upgrading users.

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that the saved preferences will be lost, it's just that Android will set it as a completely new and seperate program which cannot access the old application's preferences.

However, if you sign your applications with the same signature and and give them the same [userId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId) then they can share information and you could migrate the original application's information to the new one.

Comment: So, if they have the same signature, will the market at least remove the old application? I'm worried about the users being left with two copies!

Comment: Nope.  You can have multiple applications with the same signature.  You could remove the old application from Market, but you'll still have the installed base.

Comment: Also, any Market reviews will be lost and there won't be a smooth upgrade since it's technically seen as a new app.