# Android - Unpublishing app question

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app with an incorrect package name. Now I want to change the package name. I realize that this is going to be a brand new application on the Marketplace. There are users who have already downloaded the app.

The question is :
If unpublish my app and publish with the correct package name what would happen to the users who have already downloaded the app? Can they still keep using the app even after I unpublish?
Or
Is there a way to force these guys to make them downlod the new app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the others said, it's going to be a new app if it's a different package. You might be able to offer a smoother upgrade experience for your existing users by using the "shared userId" approach described in [Android Marketplace: Changing application's package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355217/android-marketplace-changing-applications-package)

Answer (score 2):

They keep using the app, but will not be notified for updates.
A bad way of notifying your current users is keeping the app published and updating it to only have a link to download the new app, at least for a while before unpublishing it.

Answer (score 2):

They can keep using the app, but they won't be able to update. There's no way to force them to update, but you can drop a heavy hint. Publish an update under old package ID -  a dummy app that does nothing but flash a message and redirect them to the Market page of the new app.

If you want to be user-friendly to the point of ridiculous, submit all your subsequent updates under both package names, as two apps.